# Simple search and replace in Python using recursion and user input

Tags: python, recursion, input, replace, substring

I have this simple program that takes input of a word, asks the user what part they would like to substring out and then asks what to replace it with and lastly print the result. But i need to convert it into working recursively.

I've created it in a basic sense working in Python here.

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
substring = input("Please enter the substring you wish to find: ")
new_entry = input("Please enter a string to replace the given substring: ")
new_word = word.replace(substring, new_entry)
print("Your new string is: " + new_word)
```

It should work recursively and display like:

```
Enter a word: world
Please enter the substring you wish to find: or
Please enter a string to replace the given substring PP
Your new string: is wPPld
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively"? What is expected behavior?

Comment: Heya , thats the part of the question i dont understand , I was given the completed output like i should in the display like area above , the instruction simply stated :

Comment: For this technical task you are required to create a program that implements a search
and replace function recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop, but you need to define a stop word to have a way out. In this example, I defined the stop word as quit:

```
word = ''
while (word != 'quit'):
    word = input("Enter a word: ")
    substring = input("Please enter the substring you wish to find: ")
    new_entry = input("Please enter a string to replace the given substring: ")
    new_word = word.replace(substring, new_entry)
    print("Your new string is: " + new_word)
```

I think that this is what you want, but please note that this is **not recursion**.

**EDIT:** a version of the code using recursion with the same stop word:

```
def str_replace_interface():
    word = input("Enter a word: ")
    if word != 'quit':
        substring = input("Please enter the substring you wish to find: ")
        new_entry = input("Please enter a string to replace the given substring: ")
        new_word = word.replace(substring, new_entry)
        print("Your new string is: " + new_word)
        str_replace_interface()

str_replace_interface()
```

Comment: Heya , much appreciated for the answer. I too thought a while loop to keep running the program and perhaps the instructions set out weren't clear enough. Wanted to check if i perhaps was reading this wrong and recursion was indeed possible with just the simple code.

Comment: Added a version with recursion.